# About XPath Expression

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider following XML document fragment:

`<Book>
<Title>Example</Title>
<Content>
Some line
</Content>
<TOC>
Again some line
</TOC>
</Book>`

Consider following Xpath expression:
*[not(self)::TOC]
What would be result of if current node is Book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `*[not(self)::TOC]` is not syntactically correct so you would get a syntax error.

You might want `*[not(self::TOC)]` instead which would select all child elements of the `Book` element that are not `TOC` elements so in your sample the `Title` element and the `Content` element.

Comment: Ohh..sorry tht was typo i meant wht u suggested...anyways i got answer